# How to parse Google Calendar Recurrence Rules?

Tags: google-calendar-api, ews-managed-api, google-calendar-recurring-events

I am building an application to migrate from Google Apps Calendar to Outlook Web app Calendar. I can retrieve Calendar events from Google Apps using Google Calendar Api v3 except the Recurring  events. I am getting  the recurrence field as strings defining an RRULE, EXRULE, RDATE or EXDATE rule as defined by the RFC 2445.

```
"RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;UNTIL=20110701T160000Z".
```

How to parse such Recurrence rules into various EWS managed Api  Recurrence functions and patterns ?

Is there a third party library which can help me in this regard ? Or EWS managed api has a built-in functionality to parse such Rules?

Comment: Here are a few libraries that can do it: http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/librariestools.html For example there is libical for C

Comment: thanks. is there any C# as well ?